# "To spare with my nose" meaning in this context

Tags: sentence-meaning

Text:

> I looked in the mirror
>   and saw in there
>   the end of my chin
>   and the start of my hair
>   and between there
>   isn't much space **to spare with my nose**,
>   like a handle, sticking there

This is one of the stanzas of an elementary class poem.

What is the meaning of the verb **spare** in this context? (as it usually means **to grant.**)

Answer (score 3):

The idiom is "(thing) to spare", meaning "extra (thing) left over, or available beyond the necessary amount”  (definition 6b under "spare, transitive verb" at [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spare) says: to have left over or as margin:
*time to spare*).

The poem is describing a face as the area between one's chin and one's hairline; between those two points there "isn't much space to spare" because there is a "nose, like a handle, sticking there".  (It sounds like the author thinks that their nose is a bit larger than desired.)